# Is there a jhipster json configuration specification

Tags: jhipster

I have gone through the [JHipster guides](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-guides) and seen how to use [the JHipster definition language](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/entities-fields) in JDL Studio to create entities and relationships etc, which is great.

But I am working on an application with dozens of entities already created and need to re-generate some of them after making changes to the `.json` files - but I don't see any specification of that `.json` configuration language.

I have seen suggestions to try generating a new entity (`jhipster entity book`) and look at the `.json` it outputs.

Is there no specification of what .json language at all?

Comment: Have you considered using `jhipster export-jdl` to convert your JSON entity definitions to JDL?

Comment: I think this will be a very helpful option too. I will test that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a json schema definitions for entities: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-base

Does that help?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.